# Where is regexp/syntax in codesearch?

Tags: go

https://github.com/google/codesearch/blob/master/index/regexp_test.go

`regexp/syntax` is imported in the above go file. But the codesearch also contains a regexp directory. Is `regexp/syntax` from Go system or from this local directory? Thanks.

Comment: It is from Go standard library, since local package doesn't even include "syntax" subpackage.

Comment: If it were from the same package, it would have to be imported as `github.com/google/codesearch/regexp`. If it's just `regexp/syntax`, it's from the standard library. More specifically, if the first part of the import does not contain a dot, it's from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

`regexp/syntax` is a package from the standard library, source code can be found here: https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src

Also see documentation: http://godoc.org/regexp/syntax
(also docs on a new website https://pkg.go.dev/regexp/syntax?tab=doc)

And if you want to find it on your machine:

```
$ go env

# find GOROOT and open $GOROOT/src
```